# MySQL update values using set

Tags: mysql

I want to update the value in my handicap column with the value in handicapChange column

My Table looks like:

```
Name       |   Handicap      |       Points     |          HandicapChange

Joe Bloggs |    21.00        |        39        |               20.50
```

What I want to do is update the Handicap column with the value(20.50) in HandicapChange column.
I was thinking something like:

```
update table comp SET Handicap = HandicapChange
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `UPDATE comp SET Handicap = HandicapChange WHERE Name = 'Joe Bloggs'`, otherwise you'll set these values for every record currently present in the table.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE table SET Handicap = HandicapChange` will work, but it will assign the value of HandicapChange to Handicap to EVERY row in the table. If this isn't what you want, make sure you add a `WHERE` clause targeting only those rows that you actually want to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the entire table than use that query. If you want to narrow down your set of records to update you'll need to specify parameter using WHERE.

```
update table comp SET Handicap = HandicapChange WHERE Name = 'Joe Bloggs'
```

[See MySQL for more info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).